# how to convert meteor to phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, coffeescript, meteor

I have a problem with meteor to PhoneGap
tutorial : https://github.com/guaka/meteor-phonegap#meteor2cordovacoffee
I have deploy meteor to web http://angganc.meteor.com/
I want to convert to android apk, my problem is

```
anggaranc@anggaranc-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/meteor-phonegap-master$ sudo ./meteor2cordova.coffee angganc.meteor.com --classname coba.meteor.com --appname "Meteorjs documentation" --versioncode 5 --versionname 0.6.3.1

Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/shell'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anggaranc/meteor-phonegapmaster/node_modules/execSync/index.js:24:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anggaranc/meteor-phonegap-master/meteor2cordova.coffee:11:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anggaranc/meteor-phonegap-master/meteor2cordova.coffee:4:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explored [Meteor Rider](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/MeteorRider)? I've tried a few others and this one was the most useful to get my Meteor App deployed with an APK.

Basically, you just follow the steps to create a Cordova and Meteor app as normal, but in your 
index.html for your PhoneGap app, you just have to add the following:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>

    <title>Meteor Mobile</title>

    <!-- include the core cordova JS file for your app, like normal -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery or zepto libraries, as a MeteorRider dependancy -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>

    <!-- basics for our phonegapapp (Native, on Device JS) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegapapp.js"></script>

    <!-- Meteor Rider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/meteor-rider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
    <h1>Mobile Loading...</h1>

    <div id="phonegapapp-test" style="display: none;">
        <!-- put whatever native device testing you want here, easy to toggle in phonegapapp.js -->
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // use this to track what version your user's are running
    var __MeteorRiderConfig__ = {

        // Your local dev meteor server url
        meteorUrl:  "http://192.168.0.1:3000",

        // track Cordova version, bump this after a `cordova update <platform>`
        phonegapVersion: 3.4,

        // make sure to bump this along with /www/config.xml version and build
        // to update xcodes version number. AppStore also requires >= 1.0 on submission
        phonegapAppVersion: '1.0'
    };

    // Start up the phonegap
    phonegapapp.initialize();

</script>
</body>
```

Check it out, I think you'd be quite pleased with how easy it is to use.

Comment: thank you.. my problem has been solved

I have found a complete tutorial, you can see in http://grigio.org/meteor_and_phonegap_cordova_3_x_build_native_app_android_and_ios